# call controller method from directive in requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I want to call controller function from directive of angularjs. The method also have parameters. How can I do this? I use requirejs.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy and well described in Angular guide: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive. You just have to bind the controller function to directive using `&` symbol. As Angular guide states:

> The & binding allows a directive to trigger evaluation of an expression in the context of the original scope, at a specific time.

That example copied directly from Angular guide shows how to do it:

https://plnkr.co/edit/9p3W0rMYhHN7J0EHAGRS?p=info